# JavaScript get object from json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Im new to js and i dont understand how can i take an object from json file,

for example this file : local.json

```
{
"server": "myname",
"url": 10.0.0.1
}
```

I need to get the url to insert in in my js code like this, replace the 127.0.0.1 with what i have in json file at url:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import jsonFile from '../local.json';
const http = require("http");
const host = '127.0.0.1'; #should be 10.0.0.1 from json file
```

Comment: you can access by DOT (```.```) OR SQUARE BRACKET (```[ ]```)
Example:-
```const host = jsonFile.url```
           OR
```const host = json["url"]```

Comment: The principal problem here is that your JSON isn't JSON, because you forgot to put quotes around that IP address. Once you fix that, you can access the properties in `jsonFile` in the same way you'd access any property in a standard JS object (because that's what it now is: JSON is the string representation of a JS object; once parsed, it _is_ an object, and no longer JSON string data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, Specific Object value can be accessed by following three ways:

1. DOT (`.`) operator

   ```
   const obj = {
      "server": "myname",
      "url": "10.0.0.1"
   };
   const url = obj.url;
   console.log(url); // 10.0.0.1
   ```
2. Square bracket (`[]`)

   ```
   const obj = {
      "server": "myname",
      "url": "10.0.0.1"
   };
   const url = obj["url"];
   console.log(url); // 10.0.0.1
   ```
3. De-structuring (>=ES6)

   ```
   const obj = {
      "server": "myname",
      "url": "10.0.0.1"
   };
   const { url } = obj;
   console.log(url); // 10.0.0.1
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Your json file should be:

```
{
  "server": "myname",
  "url": "10.0.0.1"
}
```

(use double quotes)

and just use dot:

```
const host = jsonFile.url
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "dot" syntax.

`const host = jsonFile.url`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to get configurations to instantiate your server.

You may like to follow below steps to instantiate settings:

Install the dependency [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config)

It allows you to define a json file of settings.

I define the structure

you create a directory inside your project called `config` inside you create a json file `default.json`

```
│
config
│--- default.json
│
```

inside the file you write your values

```
{
   "server": "myname",
   "url": "10.0.0.1"
}
```

and to access you do the following

file = index.js

```js
const config = require ("config");

console.log (config.get ("url"));
```